# Implementing a reduction operation for finding the maximum difference of numbers?

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce, reduction

I am searching for a suitable stream-based reduction operation to find the maximum difference of a double-list. (Please no solutions with old-style nested for-loops...)

Lets say my double list is
`List<Double> list = List.of(1.1, 0.3, 7.8, 1.0, 9.1, 2.3);`
then the maximum difference would result to the value
`9.1 - 0.3 = 8.8`

My first working approach with the use of java-streams is:

```
List<Double> list = List.of(1.1, 0.3, 7.8, 1.0, 9.1, 2.3);
double maxDiff = list.stream().max(Double::compareTo).get()
    - list.stream().min(Double::compareTo).get();
```

**How to implement a custom accumulator and combiner for the reduction operation **`Stream.reduce()`** to achieve the same?**

Comment: Streams are meant for stateless operations. The maximum difference in a list is not a stateless operation. What you want is not possible (well... it is, but is against the idea of streams and most probably slower than an imperative approauch). The easiest way to solve this with streams is most probably to determine the `min()` and `max()` of the list, and subtract the `min()` from the `max()`.

Comment: as `max` and `min` are already specialized methods of `reduce`, are you searching for their non-terminal implementation?

Comment: @cyberbrain - actually I was searching for a customized accumulator and combiner for the reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner) method. But I doubt, like Turing85 stated, that there is a practicable and performant solution.

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid streaming over the list twice by using the teeing collector:

```
double diff = list.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                          Collectors.reducing(Double::max),
                          Collectors.reducing(Double::min),
                          (max,min) -> max.get() - min.get()));
```

Or using summaryStatistics

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics = list.stream()
                                         .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                         .summaryStatistics();
double diff = statistics.getMax() - statistics.getMin();
```

Comment: Just as a side note, teeing is only supported on Java 12 and above.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I know that the `Optional`s in the `merger` cannot be empty, but I would suggest to replace `.get()` with `orElseThrow()`.

Comment: @Turing85 they can, with an empty `List.of()` the merger is still applied to two absent optionals and will throw a `NoSuchElementException: No value present`.

Comment: @zapl huh true. Thought the `Exception` cam from an earlier point. Nice.

Comment: there's also a slight flaw with `DoubleSummaryStatistics` because min/max for an empty list will be +Infinity and -Infinity and the diff will be -Infinity. Could be fixed by doing `double diff = statistics.getCount() > 0 ? statistics.getMax() - statistics.getMin() : 0.0;`

Answer (score 1):

For small list you could possibly make a Cartesian product of the list with itself and calculate the difference of every combination before reducing:

```
double maxDiff = list.stream()
                     .flatMap(a -> list.stream().map(b -> a - b))
                     .reduce(Double::max)
                     .get();
System.out.println(maxDiff);
```

Comment: even though not practicable nice solution :-)